# How to implement this situation (pointA - pointB)?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, implementation

Currently I'm implementing one transport service which offers collective trips, and i'm stuck in one problem:

Lets say I've got points **G** = {A,B,C,D,F,R,W} => in the picture below.

[image]

When the user selects from(A) -> to(W) there're points between them: {C,F,R}, i want to offer just the points which are connected with each others, like A->C, C->F.... and the other points shouldn't be visible in the select list. Any help any tips 'd be great, Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, are you trying to see what is connected based on a drawing?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)

Comment: I agree with Mordhawk; I think you're probably looking for the 'A*' algorithm.

Comment: Oh, you already have the points that connect A with W?  Sorry, I misread your question.  Mladen's link looks useful for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you're asking is a path finding algorithm like [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) ?